# nltk word_tokenize: why do sentence tokenization before word tokenization?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, tokenize

As noted in the [source code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py#L113), `word_tokenize` runs a sentence tokenizer(Punkt) before running the word tokenizer(Treebank):

```python
# Standard word tokenizer.
_treebank_word_tokenizer = TreebankWordTokenizer()

def word_tokenize(text, language='english', preserve_line=False):
    """
    Return a tokenized copy of *text*,
    using NLTK's recommended word tokenizer
    (currently an improved :class:`.TreebankWordTokenizer`
    along with :class:`.PunktSentenceTokenizer`
    for the specified language).
    :param text: text to split into words
    :param text: str
    :param language: the model name in the Punkt corpus
    :type language: str
    :param preserve_line: An option to keep the preserve the sentence and not sentence tokenize it.
    :type preserver_line: bool
    """
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    return [token for sent in sentences
            for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)]
```

What is the benefit of doing sentence tokenization prior to word tokenization?

Comment: Good question!!

Answer (score 3):

The default tokenizer in NLTK used (`nltk.word_tokenize`) is the [`TreebankWordTokenizer`](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py) originally from [Michael Heilman's tokenizer.sed](https://waybackmachine.org/web/20070830082400/http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~treebank/tokenizer.sed)

We see that in the `tokenizer.sed`, it states:

```
# Assume sentence tokenization has been done first, so split FINAL periods only. 
s=\([^.]\)\([.]\)\([])}>"']*\)[     ]*$=\1 \2\3 =g
```

This regex will always split the final period and the assumption is that sentence tokenization is performed beforehand.

Keeping to the treebank tokenizer, the `nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordTokenizer` performs the same regex operation and [documenting the behavior in the class docstring](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L43):

```
class TreebankWordTokenizer(TokenizerI):
    """
    The Treebank tokenizer uses regular expressions to tokenize text as in Penn Treebank.
    This is the method that is invoked by ``word_tokenize()``.  It assumes that the
    text has already been segmented into sentences, e.g. using ``sent_tokenize()``.
    This tokenizer performs the following steps:
    - split standard contractions, e.g. ``don't`` -> ``do n't`` and ``they'll`` -> ``they 'll``
    - treat most punctuation characters as separate tokens
    - split off commas and single quotes, when followed by whitespace
    - separate periods that appear at the end of line
    """
```

More specifically the "separate periods that appear at the end of line" refers to [this particular regex](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/treebank.py#L79):

```
# Handles the final period.
# NOTE: the second regex is the replacement during re.sub()
re.compile(r'([^\.])(\.)([\]\)}>"\']*)\s*$'), r'\1 \2\3 ')
```

---

**Is it common to assume sentence tokenization is performed before word tokenization?**

Maybe, maybe not; depends on your task and how you're evaluating the task. If we look at other word tokenizers, we see that they perform the same final-period split, e.g. in the [Moses (SMT) tokenizer](https://github.com/alvations/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/tokenizer/tokenizer.perl#L431):

```
# Assume sentence tokenization has been done first, so split FINAL periods only.
$text =~ s=([^.])([.])([\]\)}>"']*) ?$=$1 $2$3 =g;
```

And similarly in the [NLTK port of the Moses tokenizer](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/moses.py#L115):

```
# Splits final period at end of string.
FINAL_PERIOD = r"""([^.])([.])([\]\)}>"']*) ?$""", r'\1 \2\3'
```

Also, in [toktok.pl](https://github.com/jonsafari/tok-tok/blob/master/tok-tok.pl#L76) and its [NLTK port](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/tokenize/toktok.py#L71)

---

For users who don't want their sentence to be sentence-split, the `preserve_line` option is available since https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1710 code merge =)

For more explanation of why and what, see https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/1699

Comment: Why is this assumption necessary for the development of these word tokenizers? Is there a paper explaining the reasoning/motivation?

Comment: It looks like [treebanks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treebank) themselves are structures which "annotate syntactic or semantic sentence structure...often created on top of a corpus that has already been annotated with part-of-speech tags". So it is not necessarily that the training of these models requires the assumption but, at least with tree bank based models,  the models themselves are fundamentally built around sentences.

Comment: Good questions again! I've been asking myself the same thing, why isn't paragraph or document the default in #nlproc. Why sentence? And if we go the other way, why not morphemes? Or sentence-pieces, e.g. https://github.com/google/sentencepiece